# df style apply to specific cells

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a dict which i create df

```
data = {'BTC': {'PNL': 834.8485, 'FUNDING': 575.20837762, 'DELTA VOL': 18845436.3535, 'HEDGE VOL': 16444662.545, 'OI': 4598885.7407, 'DEFICIT': 149.35084}, 'BTC 4HR': {'PNL': 76.2125, 'FUNDING': 197.52681642, 'DELTA VOL': 1999585.538, 'HEDGE VOL': 1729156.5247, 'OI': None, 'DEFICIT': None}, 'ETH': {'PNL': -661.112, 'FUNDING': -218.42574899, 'DELTA VOL': 10720104.9915, 'HEDGE VOL': 10088271.477, 'OI': 552973.992, 'DEFICIT': 61.9926}, 'ETH 4HR': {'PNL': 65.331, 'FUNDING': 23.57589308, 'DELTA VOL': 373668.3985, 'HEDGE VOL': 356349.724, 'OI': None, 'DEFICIT': None}, 'TOTAL': {'PNL': 2859.98348042, 'FUNDING': 871.26688115, 'DELTA VOL': 33607091.07200743, 'HEDGE VOL': 30570729.07912772, 'OI': 6019831.030358, 'DEFICIT': 9250.907426}, 'TOTAL 4HR': {'PNL': 177.84871257, 'FUNDING': 246.41302914, 'DELTA VOL': 2881419.73415996, 'HEDGE VOL': 2592306.47723815, 'OI': None, 'DEFICIT': None}}
```

after creating df from this, need to make **bold** 0,0 cell 0,2 and 0,4 cells only. tried with style.applymap but couldnt succeed.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df1

def color_negative_red(val):
    try:
        if val < 0:
            color = 'red'
        elif val>0:
            color='green'
        return 'color: %s' % color
    except:
        return 'color: black'
```

also making color code changes which is working.

```
df1=df1.style.apply(styler).set_caption("Futures Risk Monitor").format("{:20,.0f}").set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'thead th',
    'props': [('text-align', 'center')]
}])
display(df1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom function, building on your existing `color_negative_red`:

```
def color_negative_red(val):
    try:
        if val < 0:
            color = 'red'
        elif val>0:
            color='green'
        return 'color: %s' % color
    except:
        return 'color: black'
    
def styler(df):
    style = df.applymap(color_negative_red)
    style.iloc[0, [0,2,4]] += '; font-weight: bold'
    return style

(df1.style.apply(styler, axis=None)
    .set_caption("Futures Risk Monitor")
    .format("{:20,.0f}")
    .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'thead th',
                        'props': [('text-align', 'center')]}])
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: getting that error, also can you change cells to 0,0 and 2,0 and 6,0

Comment: @Madan how can you have a Series? Your example shows a DataFrame. Are you sure you're using the correct name (`df1`, as you defined)?

Comment: Regarding the [0,2,6] you can adapt that yourself, however in the provided example there is no column "6" (7th column). Please clarify. If you have an error, make sure to edit your question to provide a reproducible example that triggers this error.

Comment: sharing the code for the same

Comment: im applying styler again which is causing the issue, how to rectify that

Comment: .set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'thead th',
    'props': [('text-align', 'center')]
}])

Comment: @Madan you didn't use `axis=None` in `style.apply(styler, axis=None)` like I showed, this is critical since the operations are not done per column but at the DataFrame level.

Comment: If you want to add arbitrary cells in bold, assuming `row`/`col` their positional index add extra lines of `style.iloc[row, col] += '; font-weight: bold'`.